# Get results from the first query that has data

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a requirement where I have to query three tables sequentially. But I only have to use results from the first query that has data.

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_A
WHERE MAC_ADDRESS IN ('MACADDRESS1', 'MACADDRESS2', 'MACADDRESS3');

SELECT *
FROM TABLE_B
WHERE MAC_ADDRESS IN ('MACADDRESS1', 'MACADDRESS2', 'MACADDRESS3')
AND TO_DATE(LAST_MODIFIED_DATE) >= DATEADD(DAY,-7,CURRENT_DATE());

SELECT *
FROM TABLE_C
WHERE MAC IN ('MACADDRESS1', 'MACADDRESS2', 'MACADDRESS3');
```

- Case #1: all three tables return data. Requirement: use results from `TABLE_A`
- Case #2: `TABLE_B` and `TABLE_C` return data. Requirement: use results from `TABLE_B`.
- Case #3: `TABLE_C` returns data. Requirement: use results from `TABLE_C`.

I wrapped the three queries in three CTEs but struggling to implement the requirement. Any ideas how to implement this in SQL or would I have to use a programming language.

Appreciate any ideas!

Comment: I would think using a [Stored Procedure](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures.html) is easier since it allows you to go through your use cases.

Comment: Are the columns returned by "SELECT *" equivalent? (e.g. same number of columns, same data types)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all tables have the same structure then using `UNION ALL` and priority column could solve it:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 1 AS priority,*
    FROM TABLE_A
    WHERE MAC_ADDRESS IN ('MACADDRESS1', 'MACADDRESS2', 'MACADDRESS3');
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2 AS priority, *
    FROM TABLE_B
    WHERE MAC_ADDRESS IN ('MACADDRESS1', 'MACADDRESS2', 'MACADDRESS3')
    AND TO_DATE(LAST_MODIFIED_DATE) >= DATEADD(DAY,-7,CURRENT_DATE())
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS priority, *
    FROM TABLE_C
    WHERE MAC IN ('MACADDRESS1', 'MACADDRESS2', 'MACADDRESS3')
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
QUALIFY priority = MIN(priority) OVER();
```

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 - Executable block (SP or Anonymous block). Place your logic into anonymous bloc and execute

```sql
declare -- optional
begin
    Select A .....
    if @@rowcount > 0
    begin
      --- exit logic here
    end
    -- more of your logic here for B and C
end
```

Option 2 - UNION

```sql
Select A ...
UNION ALL
Select B ...
UNION ALL
Select C ...
```

For `union` to work, you need to have same number of columns in each `select`

If this is important to know where the data come from, you can add marker field

```sql
Select t.*, 'A' marker FROM TABLE_A t ...
UNION ALL
Select t.*, 'B' marker FROM TABLE_B t ...
. . . . . . .
```

Then you can tell where the first record come from - `A`, `B` or `C`